# MongoDB Query Aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I need a query that takes multiple 'companyID's' and return the count for each company.

Currently this query only does this for one companyID and it does not return the id but just 'null' like show below.

I understand that I can use the 'in' operator for multiple companyID's but not sure how I would go about having the query return the count for multiple companyID's

```
db.getCollection('reg').aggregate([        {
                '$match' : {
                        '$and' : [
                                {
                                        'companyID'        : 11
                                },
                                {
                                        'created' : {
                                                '$gte' : 1556726597
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        'created' : {
                                                $lt : 1580572997
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                }
        },
        {
                '$project' : {

                        'testID' : 1,

                }
        },
        {
                '$group' : {
                        '_id'                : '$testID',
                        'registrationsCount' : {'$sum' : 1},
                },
        },
        { 
            $group: { 
                _id: null, 
                count: { $sum: 1 } 
            } 
        }
])
```

The result below

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "count" : 10.0
}
```

Schema below

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(1),
    "appUserID" : NumberLong(4294967295),
    "companyID" : NumberLong(5),
    "created" : NumberLong(1372625588),
    "testID" : NumberLong(11),
    "isCheckIn" : true,
    "lastModified" : NumberLong(1372625588),
    "source" : "upload",
    "timeArrived" : NumberLong(1343062512),
}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please post the schema as well? Also why is there 2 $groups?

Comment: @BalázsZákány each testID has a resigtrationCount, then other group adds all the counts from the testID's together.

Comment: I see. Did you try $_id or $testID? I think one of that should work, since the groups are created based on the _id of the $group

Comment: @BalázsZákány could you elaborate ? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do 2 things
first

```
'$match' : {
  '$or': [
    '$and' : [
      {
        'companyID'        : 11
      },
      {
        'created' : {
          '$gte' : 1556726597
        }
      },
      {
        'created' : {
          $lt : 1580572997
        }
      }
    ]
    // ... add the other ids you need
  ]
}
```

And second

```
{
  '$group' : {
    '_id'                : '$testID',
    'registrationsCount' : {'$sum' : 1},
  },
},
{ 
  $group: { 
    _id: '$testID', // or '$_id' not sure
    count: { $sum: 1 } 
  } 
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the input here but what I am wanted is a query that I can query muitple companyID's and the query to return the count for EACH companyID. e.g multiple objects returned with the count of testID

Comment: Sorry, than the $group _id should be the companyID. But then you need to add that to the projection